# EclipseLink JPA: list entities with reference variables

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am using JPA's eclipseLink to perform CRUD operations on my entities. I am facing following problem:

I have two tables in DB:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   signUpDate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE TABLE Friendship (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   friendsSince timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
   user1_Id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES User(id),
   user2_Id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES User(id)
);
```

The corresponding Entities

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date signUpDate;
    // constructors & setters & getters ...
}

@Entity
public class Friendship {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user1_Id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user1;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user2_Id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user2;
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date friendsSince;

    // constructors & setters & getters ... 
}
```

If I want to retrieve a list of some entities, according to "WHERE" clause of a query I get this "unknown state or association field [user1_Id] of class [com.filip.xxx.Friendship]" error.

Specifically: 
I try to build this query:

```
Query query = mgr.createQuery("select f.id ,f.friendsSince, f.user1_Id, f.user2_Id from Friendship f where f.user1_Id = :user1Id and f.user2_Id = :user2Id or f.user1_Id = :user11Id and f.user2_Id = :user12Id");
```

and recieve this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [select f.id ,f.friendsSince, f.user1_Id, f.user2_Id from Friendship f where f.user1_Id = :user1Id and f.user2_Id = :user2Id or f.user1_Id = :user11Id and f.user2_Id = :user12Id], line 1, column 31: unknown state or association field [user1_Id] of class [com.filip.xxx.Friendship].
```

It seems like there is a problem with mapping attributes back to the entities, because I have no problem with persisting these two entities.

And interesting is that, if I run this query:

```
Query query = mgr.createQuery("select f from Friendship f");
```

It returns me the correct list of all friendships entities.

Notice that the reference variable's name in friendship entity(user1, user2) are not the same as corresponding table's variables (user1_Id, user2_Id). Before I have used the same variable names in entity as in table, but recieved this error at persisting friendship entity:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'USER1_ID' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO FRIENDSHIP (FRIENDSSINCE, USER1_ID, USER2_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
```

Basically I don't understand, why eclipse link renames the entity's reference variables (user1 -> USER1_ID, user2 -> USER2_ID) when creating sql query, when it has than problems to map it back to the entities.

I have already tried these solutions:
Build query and return user1_Id column as user1 and user2_Id as user2

```
select f.id ,f.friendsSince, f.user1_Id as user1, f.user2_Id as user2 from Friendship f where f.user1_Id = :user1Id and f.user2_Id = :user2Id or f.user1_Id = :user11Id and f.user2_Id = :user12Id
```

but recieved the same IllegalArgumentException as above.

Could you help me solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception

`unknown state or association field [user1_Id] of class [com.filip.xxx.Friendship]`

is received because you are using `user1_Id` name which is a database column name.

From the other hand `ElementManager.createQuery()` method expects JPQL string which accepts the entity's field name `user1`. Try to replace your query string with:

```sql
select f.id, f.friendsSince, f.user1, f.user2
from Friendship f 
where f.user1 = :user1Id and 
      f.user2 = :user2Id or 
      f.user1 = :user11Id and 
      f.user2 = :user12Id
```